# adjust image size in script jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm not familiar with Javascript coding as much as I do with HTML. Just want to ask, how to re-size images within this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "img/img1.jpg" 
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "img/img2.jpg"
</script>
```

I have worked it out in HTML by using this code, and I have no idea how to work my around in Javascript though:

```
<img src="img/www.png" alt="Logo" width="250" height="150" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left:60px;" >
```

Your kind reply would be greatly appreciated.

McJim

*sorry here is the complete code:

```
<?php include('variables/variables.php'); ?>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript">

var image1 = new Image()
image1.src = "img/img1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image()
image2.src = "img/img2.jpg"
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p><img src="images/pentagg.jpg" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<2)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

This is actually one php file, and is called from another php file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
var image1 = new Image(250, 150);
```

so it is `new Image(width, height)`

Here are some docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement.Image?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FImage#Image_Element_constructor

**EDIT reflecting new code added by OP**

The problem is you aren't adding the images to the DOM, the webpage itself. **Move the script into the body** just above the other script and change the code to this:

```
var image1 = new Image(250, 150)
image1.src = "img/img1.jpg"
var image2 = new Image(350, 200)
image2.src = "img/img2.jpg"
var body = document.querySelector('body');
body.appendChild(image1);
body.appendChild(image2);
```

Here is a functioning JSBin example: http://jsbin.com/AzAvunOm/1/edit?html,output

So your code should look like this (you will have to adjust it for exactly what you want):

```
<?php include('variables/variables.php'); ?>

<head>
</head>
<body>
<p><img src="images/pentagg.jpg" width="500" height="300" name="slide" /></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var image1 = new Image(250, 150)
    image1.src = "img/img1.jpg"
    var image2 = new Image(350, 200)
    image2.src = "img/img2.jpg"
    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    body.appendChild(image1);
    body.appendChild(image2);
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
        var step=1;
        function slideit()
        {
            document.images.slide.src = eval("image"+step+".src");
            if(step<2)
                step++;
            else
                step=1;
            setTimeout("slideit()",2500);
        }
        slideit();
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried using this code, but it didn't really do anything. My guess is that its contradicting other codes, since my codes are mixed with html & php, i am not sure. Let me edit my question, sorry for missing out information.

Comment: Yes, you are creating the images in javascript, but you aren't actually adding them to the webpage, the "DOM". Move the script into the body, just above the other script, then add these lines: var body = document.querySelector('body'); body.appendChild(image1); body.appendChild(image2);` You should see something, adjust your code to make it look like what you want. I will adjust my answer with the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can sett height and width as follows.

```
image1.width = 250;
image1.height = 150;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u need something like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>

<script type="text/javascript">


 function changesize(){
   var  myid=document.getElementById('myimg');
   myid.with=300;
   myid.height=300;
  }

function changesize2(){
var  myid=document.getElementById('myimg');
myid.with=200;
myid.height=100;
}
</script>


<img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTe0LZa5KiYoWxGAC-_5gP2MoOuBx8QkCWLGeCuE01-0UPNrOVhrsTeNcvD" id='myimg' alt="Logo" width="250" height="150" style="position: absolute; top: 10px; left:60px;" >



<button type='submit' value='Btn1' name='Btn1' onclick="changesize()" >
<button type='submit' value='Btn2' name='Btn2'  onclick="changesize2()" >

</body>
</html>
```